# Regex to select a pattern of SubString

Tags: c#, regex

What is the syntax for finding and selecting part of a string in Regx C#?

The string could be:

```
string tdInnerHtml = "<strong> You gained  230 Points </strong> 
                      there is going to be more text and some html code part of this       
                      string <a href=http://google.com>Google it here </a>";

// I want to extract 230 from this string using Regx. 
// The digits (230) vary for each tdInnerHtml. 
// So code would be to look for digits, followed by space, ending with Points
```

Comment: Are you parsing HTML? Use an Html parser, not Regex. That path leads to unspeakable things.

Comment: I am using HTML parser but needs to get the the SubString value inside the  TD cell.

Comment: Your parser should understand how to pull attributes and content from an element. Perhaps it's hiding in the documentation?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the space and the `</strong>` tag are consistent, you can use the following to get the match there, and will work with strings like: " **Pints are between 230-240 Points and You gained 230 Points** "

```
        var match = Regex.Match(tdInnerHtml, @"(?<pts>\d+) Points ?</strong>");
        if (match.Success) {
            int points = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["pts"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Points: {0}", points);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The </strong> is not consistent.  "230 Points" could be anywhere inside the string.

Comment: Which part is consistent?  Is the "You gained ? Points" consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex pattern might be `\b[0-9]+\b \bPoints\b`.

You might test this at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're only going for a set of numbers followed by the text `Points`, Regex can work:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(tdInnerHtml, @"(?<![\d-])(\d+) Points");
if (match.Success){
  // fetch result
  String pointsString = match.Groups[1].Value;

  // optional: parse to integer
  Int32 points;
  if (Int32.TryParse(pointsString, out points)){
    // you now have an integer value
  }
}
```

However, if this is in any way related to where the information resides on the page, formatting its surrounded by, or anything else HTML related--heed others' warnings and use an HTML parser.

Comment: thanks for the reply. If I have a value of: string test = "<strong> Pints are between 230-240 Points and You gained 230 Points </strong>"; your code returns 240. But I want exactly 230 followed by "Points".

Comment: @Shuaib: Use a negative look-behind to assert the `\d` isn't preceded by a hyphen or number. Basically, change the above code to: `@"(?<![\d-])(\d+) Points"` -- [Example](http://ideone.com/Qj930)

Answer (score 0):

The regex is very easy, `\d+ Points`. Here it is in C#, with a named group capture:

```
        var match = Regex.Match(tdInnerHtml, "(?<pts>\d+) Points");
        if (match.Success) {
            int points = (int)match.Groups["pts"].Value;
            // do something..
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "<strong> You gained 230 Points </strong>";
string pattern = @"(\d+)\sPoints";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(test);
string result = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "";
```